# How can I get the value out of a run method?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, timer, local

I have two frames. The first has a button. By clicking it a second frame is opened and a timer starts. The second frame can be closed by pressing the button again or by waiting until the timer has incremented a local variable `x` to three. I had several approaches.

1. The button started only the timer and within the run method of the timer, the second frame was opened. When the timer incremented the variable `x` to three the second frame closed. It worked properly. The problem was that I wasn't able to close the frame by pressing the button again. So I tried the following.
2. The button opens the second frame and the second frame contains an object of the timer. Now I can close the second frame by clicking on the button again. But it won't close when the timer has incremented `x` to three because the second frame is now out of the run method and has no more access to the local variable `x`.

And here is my problem. I just don't know how to get the value of `x` out of the run method.  The run method allows no parameters to pass the value. To access it with `timerClass.x` doesn't change anything. Here the code.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FrameOne frameOne = new FrameOne ();
}}
```

.

```
///////////////////////////////////////     THE FIRST FRAME 

public class FrameOne extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private FrameTwo frameTwo;
private JButton btn= new JButton();

///////////////////////    PROPERTIES OF THE FIRST FRAME

FrameOne(){

    btn.addActionListener(this);
    add(btn);
    setSize(400,400);
    setLocation(300, 250);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}


///////////////////////     OPENS THE SECOND FRAME BY CLICKING THE BUTTON

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                

    if (e.getSource() == btn && frameTwo == null) {

            frameTwo = new FrameTwo();  
}


///////////////////////     CLOSES THE SECOND FRAME BY CLICKING THE BUTTON AGAIN


    else if (e.getSource() == btn && frameTwo != null) {  

            frameTwo.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frameTwo, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
            frameTwo = null;
    }}

}
```

.

```
///////////////////////////////////////     THE SECOND FRAME


public class FrameTwo extends JDialog {

TimerClass timerClass;

FrameTwo() {


    setSize(400,400);
    setLocation(900, 250);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    timerClass = new TimerClass();  // starts the timer


//////////////////////////     HERE I TRY TO LET THE TIMER CLOSE THE FRAME AT 3    ////////

    if(timerClass.x == 3) {this.dispatchEvent(
        new WindowEvent(
            this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
               }}}
```

.

```
//////////////////       THE TIMER       
//////////////////       IT INCREMENTS x
//////////////////       WHEN x = 3 IT SHALL CLOSE THE FRAME 


public class TimerClass implements EventListener{

            public Timer timer = new Timer(true);
            public int x;

    TimerClass(){

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                x++;
        }

    },0,1000);
}}
```

I was also recommended to use `frameTwo.dispose();` instead of the `this.dispatchEvent` command. Or use `frameTwo.dispatchEvent` and so on. Nothing ever worked. I know that it is because I am not familiar enough with passing values of variables. Please don't give me a hind to use tutorials. I need to know it from this example to make quick progress. It is my way of learning. Thank you for your sympathy and your efforts.

Comment: @Sandeep Kumar  Thanks for your improvements. I honestly try to make as less mistakes as possible. I didn't recognized that it was that bad.

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix would be to move the `timerClass.x == 3` check into the timer class as such:

In class `FrameTwo` replace:

```
timerClass = new TimerClass();  // starts the timer
```

with

```
timerClass = new TimerClass(()->this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING)));
```

In class `TimerClass` replace the constructor:

```
TimerClass(){

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                x++;
        }

    },0,1000);
```

with

```
TimerClass(Runnable runWhenThree) {    
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    x++;
                    if(x == 3) {
                        runWhenThree.run();
                    }                       
                }    
            }, 0, 1000);
        }
```

Comment: Wow. That was a fast answer. Thank you. I have red so often the word **Runnable** in the past. What is that exactly? And What does **()->** in ** new TimerClass()** means? Is it the reference to the **Runnable**?

Comment: Sorry. I am new to the forum. I try to markdown my comments better next time. But the time to edit was over.

Comment: Runnable is just an interface with one method (run).  
`()->this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING))` is simply a shorter way of writing `new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     FrameTwo.this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(FrameTwo.this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
    }
   }`

Comment: This is like creating a method beforehand and then giving that method to the TimerClass to call it when x==3.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. It helps me a lot. Can I use it always that way if I have method that doesn't allow parameters or when I deal with anonymous static methods?

Comment: You don't have to, as an alternative you could also hand over the object directly, like this:
`TimerClass(FrameTwo frameToClose) {
   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     x++;
     if(x == 3) {
      frameToClose.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frameToClose, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
     }
    }
   }, 0, 1000);
  }`

Comment: Because the `run` method of the `TimerClass` is in the scope of the `TimerClass` constructor, all variables from this scope (including the `runWhenThree` variable fromt he answer and the `frametoClose` variable from the comment) are visible and accessible inside the method as well.

Comment: But your way is the quickest I guess. Wow. Amazing. I love it. I will learn all the ways by heart so I will be able to use it with closed eyes. Thank you so much.